# How to find all Test Suites a particular Test Case belongs to

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

I have a Test Case in Microsoft Test Manager 2010 that is used in a Test Plan.

How can I find this Test Case in the Test Plan? Is there at least a column in the Organize view that shows the paths of the Test Plans where the Test Case is used?

Comment: You can search for Test Cases programatically using TFS API. Which TFS version are you running?

Comment: TFS is running in version 2013.

Comment: The only way I know (and I'm actually often using for similar tasks) is to use TFS API. I've just added a code snippet that works for me with TFS 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, *MTM* UI does not provide any possibility to search for *Test Cases*.

**Edit:** (see comment)
Unfortunately, *MTM* UI does not provide any possibility to search for *Test Cases* that belong to a particular *Test Plan* or *Test Suite*.

**May be a solution for you:**
You can check to which *Test Suites* a particular *Test Case* belongs to using *TFS-API*. 
Here is a code snipped that works on TFS 2013:

```cs
// Current user credentials will be used to access to TFS
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(<TFS Url>));
tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

ITestManagementService testManagementService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
ITestManagementTeamProject  teamProject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(<team project name>);

// Get all Test Suites your Test Case belongs to
// (Across all Test Plans in the Team Project)
ITestSuiteCollection testSuites = teamProject.TestSuites.ReferencingTestCase(testCaseId);
```

Have a look at the [ITestManagementTeamProject Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestmanagementteamproject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can do a lot with it.
(**Hint:** currently this interface is absolutely not documented for *VS 2013* so switch the page to *VS 2012* and you will usually find a little more documentation).
For your task on building a whole path to the particular *Test Suite* check [ITestSuiteHelper Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestsuitehelper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ITestSuiteBase Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestsuitebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They provide you with data you need to follow the *Test Suites*' tree of your project.

Comment: This is not exactly true. You have in the 'Organize'->'Test Case Manager' the possibility to filter the Test Cases, but you don't get any information, where the Test Cases are located in the Test Plans.

Comment: That what I actually meant since that was your question ;). I've just improved the answer.

Comment: Thanks, your code is quite helpful. But my problem is, that I already knew that the TestCase is in this TestPlan, but as it is a big TestPlan with a lot of branches (and subbranches...) it is quite hard to find the right branch. From the linked WIQL document I don't see how this tree is built. Can you give me a hint (or even better entend the code)?

Comment: How do you represent branches in your test plan? Do you have a Test Suite for each branch/subbranch? If so would it be enough to know the names of the Test Suites the test case belongs to? Or do you want to have the whole "path" in the tree?

Comment: Yes, exactly the last one. The Test Plan contains a big tree, so opening every branch of the tree is really anoying... So I look for a way to get the path from the root node of the tree through all branches, so I can then follow this path in the MTM.

Comment: I've just extended my answer. It should contain all information you need.